Is this token a scam? (ABYS)
I was recently browsing the list of new pools on arbitrum and came across this coin: https://arbiscan.io/address/0xd7d39c9fa965b8b2458f2f6100f78e5ad1b318fe
Without looking too much into it, I saw a pool for it on geckoterminal within a minute of it's implementation and saw the pool had a decent amount of initial liquidity, so I decided to throw 20 bucks in there to see what happens.
I now have about 350 dollars worth of ABYS, and I can not get it to sell on sushiswap. When I purchased, it notified me that the coin had a tax, so I thought that may be the problem, but I have not been able to sell even when increasing slippage tolerance to 100%.
The contract on arbiscan has some weird variable names in there and a generic contract name so I am pretty sure like this is a scam, but was hoping someone who knows a little more than me could verify. The contract also claims it is "for development", but idk if that is legit or also a common disclaimer by scammers since this was a publicly released pool on sushiswap.
Looking to learn so I can either cash out my coin or not make this mistake again in the future!

I've no idea but if some code use private when not needed and have an interface named YVZAVsbUgvPSjWmDHFPrPN I'd assume the worse.
